# HttpClient 401 unauthorized at 1st, 3rd, 5th requests but successful at 2nd, 4th, 6th when calling ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I'm facing one issue when calling web api with httpclient (console program)

- The requests failed (401, unauthorzied) at **1st, 3rd, 5th, etc**
  requests
- The requests succeed at **2nd, 4th, 6th**, etc requests

**Program.cs**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var token = GlobalVariables.GetAccessToken();
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("TOKEN");
    Console.WriteLine($"Token : {token.Token}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Expires : {token.ExpiresIn}");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("3");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("4");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("5");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    Console.WriteLine("6");
    Console.WriteLine("================================");
    CallApiEndpoint(ApiUrl, token.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("================================");

    Console.Read();
}

static void CallApiEndpoint(string url, string token)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
        }
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<User>();
    PublicClientId = "self";

    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
        Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        AllowInsecureHttp = true
    };

    app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
}
```

**Response**

[image: Response]

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of investigating this matter, I finally found out that the `401 unauthorized` was due to `Load Balancer` on infrastructure level (`IIS`).

so I simply put `MachineKey` in web.config

Hope it helps someone.

Comment: What was the reason exaclty and how did you configure `machineKey`?

Comment: @andreycha: the reason is the `load balancer` keep switching the endpoint server and the server is using `machineKey` to decrypt and validate the token